# Does Capistrano need to be in the development group in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

In a rails Gemfile, does `gem 'capistrano'` need to be inside the `:development` group or this there any advantage in putting it inside an arbitrary group like `:tools`?

Comment: If you consider your question "answered" by my response and our dialog below, could you please mark it as such so that it will appear as resolved to the community? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the heads up and sorry for the wait. Travel got in the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, no, it doesn't **need** to be, but it's good for the sake of best practices and keeping your gemsets uncluttered. The best way to do that is open for debate, but basically as long as Capistrano is available to you in the environment you're working in, it doesn't matter what groups it is or isn't associated with, though I can see little to no advantage of using an arbitrary `:tools` group since `:development` will exclude it in production cleanly and "auto-magically" in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't putting something in `:development` automatically load it while in the dev environment, or is that something I just made up? Seems like it would be a good idea to keep it out of there, even if it's just to make the app in dev use less memory. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, it does. Capistrano, however is a command-line utility which really should only be eating memory when called. The overhead to have Capistrano "loaded" in the dev gemset is quite minimal, and the biggest reason for keeping it out of production in my book isn't so much performance but appropriateness - since you don't deploy from production, why eat space on your drive to install your deployment tool?  Are you seeing any particular performance issues on your dev system with Capistrano installed vs. not?

Comment: Keeping it out of production is a given; we agree on that. Also, my app isn't big enough yet for me to have any performance issues regardless of cap's location in the Gemfile, so you're right in suggesting to keep it of production (and testing) and just shove it into development. I was just wondering if that's the smart thing to do, especially when the app starts to grow and you start to add things like guard gems etc.

Comment: You really shouldn't see many issues going forward then. If you start running guard, you'll see some delay in performance while guard monitors and then runs its tasks, but when idle between events, even guard runs pretty lean too. In any case, cap is dormant until you need it, and I've never taken a noticeable hit running my dev environments on what is now 4-year old hardware based on Capistrano's presence.