# delayed_job gem won't start in production (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, delayed-job

I'm having a problem with getting delayed_job to start in the production environment. Everything works as it should in development just using the rake jobs:work command, but after deploying to my server with Capistrano, and hours of failed attempts later, I cannot figure out how to get DJ running.

As it says to do on the github repository for delayed_job, I made sure I bundled the "daemons" gem, and also attempted to start it with the command "bin/delayed_job start" instead of "script/delayed_job start" since I'm on rails 4. I've also ran the required generator "rails generate delayed_job" which did generate this file inside the bin directory of my project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

The error I'm consistently getting is `-bash: bin/delayed_job: No such file or directory` which I think could be since I'm using rvm.

As for my gemfile, I've included delayed_job_active_record and daemons. At this point I'm completely stumped and out of links to explore.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
 # Rails defaults
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bundler' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
 # learn-rails
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails', :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.rc'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.0.0'
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem "faker", "~> 1.2.0"
end
group :production do
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'pg'
gem 'daemons'
end
```

Comment: Is it OK, that you have capistrano gems only for :development and :test in your Gemfile?

Comment: @Leger, yes it's okay to have Capistrano in development, a good answer that clarifies that topic further: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661804/2922050

Comment: A couple things I had to do to get this working for myself.  Can you ssh into the server and rake the database again, run ```RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate```.  Every once in a while new migrations are not run for me personally when I deploy, so this is necessary.  

Also post the delayed_job.log file, found here ```application_name/log/delayed_job.log```

Can you verify the presence of the bin/delayed_job file on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first line in bin/delayed_job points to a valid Ruby executable. You're using just `ruby` which probably can't be resolved. rvm is adding the full path to ruby when you cd into the rails_root directory, but that's not happening when the script is executed. One slightly hacky solution would be to cd into the directory, do a `which ruby` and write that into bin/delayed_job, such as: `#!<path_to_ruby>`. No need to call `/usr/bin/env` since Capistrano is doing this already.